# How to prevent "A possible object cycle was detected"

Tags: blazor

I have 2 models Piece and Publisher.

```
public class Publisher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Piece>? Pieces { get; set; }
}

public class Piece
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Publisher? Publisher { get; set; }
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }
}
```

With it like this with that [JsonIgnore] it'll work, but what if I want to get the Pieces that a Publisher is associated with. From the Piece I can get the Publisher just fine, but not in the opposite direction.  If the [JsonIgnore] is not there I get a "A possible object cycle was detected" exception. How can I also get Pieces from the Publisher?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using Linq to SQL there should not be any issues, however I do recommend using the serializer setting `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an obvious circularity, and I'd recommend you re-think your data structures rather than try to find some loophole that will allow you to compile.

A `Publisher` and `Pieces` are distinct entities, and I wouldn't include reference in either to the other, beyond the `PublisherID` in the `Piece` class.

If you really want your `Publisher` object to have a `List<Piece>`, that's fine-- so long as you don't automatically load them all every time you want to list your publishers.

However, **Containing the entire parent object in the child is a no-no.  Don't do it.**

If you want to get the Publisher info for a collection of `Piece` objects (e.g. if you've searched for them by title), then you can do that.

Comment: So rather than calling all associated Pieces when calling each Publisher, call the Pieces as I need them?  For instance if I want to make a table of Publishers, and show the Pieces associated, just call the Publishers without the Pieces, then in the foreach make a call for Pieces associated with that particular Publisher?  In that case as it runs through each instance it'll create and dispose, instead of having everything all in memory?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  If you don't have much data, you could load both tables  
 in their entirety (maybe in a Singleton service), then use `Where` clauses at display time.  If you have massive amounts of data, then I'd probably list all the Publishers with a count of books for each, and then load the `Pieces` on demand (say, when you click on a Publisher).  The only advice I can definitely give is this: don't be afraid to run multiple queries-- for simple data like this, you can run hundreds of queries per second off a SQL server.